zsh why and how to fix Completion error running command: "trial"
Why do I get this error when using zsh and how to fix?
Completion error running command: "trial" "foo" "--_shell-completion" "zsh:2"
If output below is unhelpful you may need to edit this file and redirect stderr to a file.
Expected completion function, but instead got:


Reproduction steps:
zsh -f  # Launch clean zsh without any rc files
autoload -U compinit
compinit
trial foo  # Press tab

If I run foobar foo<tab> no errors, where both trial and foobar are not executables. If it's not an executable or missing completion file, then it should fallback to completing a file path, which is what I want, but trial seems to be some sort of special command messes up autocompletion? Note that trial or _trial are not in any of the $fpath directories.
Tested on zsh 5.8 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu) and zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0).
This is particularly a problem for someone that does have a command-line tool called trial and zsh just spits out errors.

Definitively a +1 for providing minimal steps to reproduce and giving the program versions.

This message is caused by the completion definition file Completion/Unix/Command/_twisted from where I quote:

This is the ZSH completion file for Twisted commands. It calls the current command-line with the special "--_shell-completion" option which is handled by twisted.python.usage. t.p.usage then generates zsh code on stdout to handle the completions for this particular command-line.

So to my understanding for those commands defined herein (i.e. twist, twistd, trial, conch, cftp, ckeygen, pyhtmlizer, tkconch) zsh tries to invoke the command to generate the completins on thy fly. But if the command is not installed, this will fail, hence this cryptic error message.
Probably two, maybe three solutions:

Install the trial command.

Delete the completion definition file _twisted.

Disable the completion for trial by issuing:
compdef -d trial



The last options seems to be the most targeted one, but it depends on your specific case.
